# Understanding the grid-column property

Tags: css, css-grid

I recently answered a question about CSS grid.

But in my answer I used a style that worked, but against what I believe would be the standard way.

Take a look at the following snippet.

The red cell has this style:

```
grid-column: 3 / 4;
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.cell {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.cell:nth-child(10n + 1) {
  background: red;
  grid-column: 3 / 4;  
  grid-row: span 2;
}


.cell:nth-child(10n + 1):hover {
  grid-column: 3 / 5;  /* strange behaviour */
}

.cell:nth-child(10n + 2),
.cell:nth-child(10n + 4) {
  background: papayawhip;
  grid-column: 2;

}

.cell:nth-child(10n + 6),
.cell:nth-child(10n + 8) {
  background: yellowgreen;
  grid-column: 4;
}

.cell:nth-child(10n + 7),
.cell:nth-child(10n + 9) {
  background: yellow;
  grid-column: 3;
}

.cell:nth-child(10n + 10) {
  background: lightblue;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;    /* strange behaviour */
  grid-row: span 2;

}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">1</div>
  <div class="cell">2</div>
  <div class="cell">3</div>
  <div class="cell">4</div>
  <div class="cell">5</div>
  <div class="cell">6</div>
  <div class="cell">7</div>
  <div class="cell">8</div>
  <div class="cell">9</div>
  <div class="cell">10</div>
  <div class="cell">11</div>
  <div class="cell">12</div>
  <div class="cell">13</div>
  <div class="cell">14</div>
  <div class="cell">15</div>
  <div class="cell">16</div>
  <div class="cell">17</div>
  <div class="cell">18</div>
  <div class="cell">19</div>
  <div class="cell">20</div>
  <div class="cell">21</div>
  <div class="cell">22</div>
  <div class="cell">23</div>
</div>
```

But it fail to go to the 4 column.

I you hover it, however, the style

```
grid-column: 3 / 5;
```

will make it expand to the 4th column

I would believe this to be a bug, but Chrome and FF are consistent .

So, there must be something that I don't understand .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply a misunderstanding of what the values of the `grid-column` property mean.

A grid is separated by lines. And `grid-column: 3 / 4;` means that this item starts at the third line and ends at the fourth line. It does not mean that this item will span over the third and fourth column. I quickly visualized the *lines* with their corresponding counter in the following snippet.

```css
.grid {
  width: 200px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-column-gap: 0px;
  counter-reset: count;
}

.cell {
  position: relative;
  background: lightgrey;
  border-left: 3px solid orange;
}

.cell:last-child {
  border-right: 3px solid orange;
}

.cell:before {
  counter-increment: count;
  content: counter(count);
}

.cell:last-child:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  counter-increment: count;
  content: counter(count);
}
```

```html
<p>Setting <code>grid-column: 3 / 5;</code> on a cell will make this cell span from the third orange line to the fifth.</p>

<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I knew there should be an explanation ...  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44708439/3597276), `grid-column: 3 / 4` means the grid area covers grid column ***lines*** three to four. In other words, it covers the third column alone.

You were apparently thinking that this rule would cover grid ***columns*** three and four. Actually, that's also possible in Grid:

- `grid-column: 3 / span 2`
- `grid-column: 3 / 5`

Keep in mind, in a four column grid, there are five grid column lines. In fact, in every grid the number of column / row lines is equal to the number of columns / rows + 1, because the last column / row has an extra (final) line.

Firefox offers a useful tool for seeing this.

In Firefox dev tools, when you inspect the grid container, there is a tiny grid icon in the CSS declaration. On click it displays an outline of your grid.

[image]

More details here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_grid_layouts

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wasn't aware of this feature in FF (I mostly use Chrome), and it's very interesting