# Grid item doesn't leave one grid cell

Tags: html, css, css-grid

As you can see, I have divided `.content` div into five equal columns. I wanted to make navigation (`nav`) be in the center of the last two of the columns.

I specified that its location should be on `4 / 5` and also added `justify-self: center` for centering, but apparently, the element is just stuck on the 4th column. I also inspected it and It doesn't leave one column no matter what. How do I fix this?

```css
.content {
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
  grid-template-rows: 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10% 10%;
}

.content nav {
  grid-column: 4 / 5;
  grid-row: 1;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

.content nav a {
  margin: 0cm 0.5cm 0cm 0.5cm;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <nav>
    <a href="#">Text #1</a>
    <a href="#">Text #2s</a>
    <a href="#">Text #3</a>
    <a href="#">Text #4</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: grid-column: 4 / 6; or grid-column: 4 / span 2; 4 / 5 includes only 1 track (from 4th to 5th line)

Comment: also better use 1fr instead of percentage, you will make it shorter and easier

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44706536/3597276

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grid-column: 4 / 5` does not work as you expect because numbers 4 and 5 do not represent grid cells but rather grid *lines*.

Take a look at this picture:

[image: Take a look a this picture]

`grid-column: 3 / 5` here means *position this area between column lines 3 and 5*.

As @VXp said in the comments - set it to `grid-column: 4 / 6` or `grid-column: 4 / span 2` and that should do it.

Here's a good [guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) that thoroughly covers css grid.